# How to highlight specific lines in Ace Editor Angular Project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ace-editor

I am not able to highlight specific lines in ace editor.
I didn't find any package for the same.

app.component.css

```
.myMarker {
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(100,200,100,0.5);
  z-index:20
}
```

app.component.html

```
<ace-editor #editor [text]="text" style="min-height: 200px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"></ace-editor>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import{ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import 'brace/theme/merbivore';
import 'brace/mode/golang';
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('editor') editor;
    text: string = " func main() {\n{\na := []float64{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}\nmean := stat.Mean(a, nil)\nfmt.Println(mean)\n}";

    ngAfterViewInit() {

        this.editor.setTheme("merbivore");
        this.editor.setMode("golang");
        this.editor.getEditor().setOptions({
          enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
          enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
          enableSnippets: true,
        });
       var ace = require('brace');
    var Range = ace.acequire('ace/range').Range;
this.editor.getEditor().session.addMarker(new Range(2, 0, 0, 1), 'myMarker', 'fullLine', true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either compile a go linter to javascript similar to what is done https://dmitri.shuralyov.com/blog/24, and create a worker file (i suggest to open issue on ace repository asking to help with the worker part https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace),
Or you can run the linter on the server.